# How to force Ebean to do a Left join, not a join?

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

With PlayFramework, I use Ebean to make a query where the OneToMany are null, but Ebean generate a simple "JOIN" query, that returns no rows. If a change it to "LEFT JOIN" in MySQL, it works, but I don't know how to do it via Ebean.

Here's the code :

```
List<User> list = User.find().isNull("documents.type").findList();
```

Here's the generated SQL :

```
select {columns} from users t0 join user_documents t1 on t1.user_id = t0.id  
where t1.type is null
order by t0.lastname, t0.firstname
```

This returns no entry. But If I manually change this query by adding LEFT JOIN, I have results (correct).

How can I force Ebean to make a LEFT JOIN instead of a simple JOIN ?

Comment: Did you find a way without native sql?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like (untested)

```
User.find().fetch("documents.type").findList();
```